# Why does saving my kivy file with .kv only tends to return .kv.py?

Tags: python, string, kivy

I recently have put a hand on the kivy framework and I am trying to save my kivy file as .kv so as to connect it to my main.py file but unfortunately it gets saved as .kv.py. How is that?

Again in my .kv file it keeps telling me invalid syntax here `<MyWidget>`: Which I think everything is right. How is that?

I am including the code here:

**.kv file**

```
<MyWidget>:

Button:
    text: 'hello'
    pos:0,100
    size:100,50
    color:.8,.9,0,1
    font_size:32
Butoon:
    text: 'world'
    pos:100, 0
    size:100,50
    color:.8,.9,0,1
    font_size:32
```

Comment: (If this is copy-pasted here, `Butoon` is not the same as `Button`.)

Comment: The code below your <MyWidget> should be indented an extra line -- not sure if that's how you actually have it written in your file. You can probably rename your file just using Finder (mac) or File Explorer (Windows) and that should do the trick.

Comment: How are you saving the file? Are you using an IDE like `pycharm`?